# Does removal of "OPTIONSVerbHandler" and "TRACEVerbHandler" kill the website on iis?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have application hosting on IIS server. I was told to remove "OPTIONSVerbHandler" and "TRACEVerbHandler" from the IIS as a security measure. I just wanted to confirm that Does removal of "OPTIONSVerbHandler" and "TRACEVerbHandler" kill the website on iis? Also when i checked IIS handler mapping i couldn't find "TRACEVerbHandler" instead i found "TraceHandler-Integrated". so is this the one that i am looking for?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Removing OPTIONSVerbHandler might cause a problem if you have CORS setup. Removing TRACEVerbHandler won't hurt anything, it will just disable tracing from working. And yes you want to remove TraceHandler-Integrated too, and TraceHandler-Integrated-4.0 as well in case it's installed on the server.